# How to check for the nodata cells in a raster image

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, nodata

Please let me know how to check for the locations of nodata cells in raster images  in ArcMap. The raster images has no attribute table.

Comment: Do you have a spatial analyst license? If so you can use the function IsNull https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000m8000000 followed by raster to polygon https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000008000000 and select the polygons where GRIDCODE = 1 (null) to find the null cells locations.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. yes I have licensee. I am wondering if there is a method that I can use to detect nodata locations  directly  from raster. The raster images with fine resolutions and converting to polygon could take a lot of time

Comment: I don't have ArcMap, but you can make some raster algebra to create a white raster with black pixels where there are nodata values. For example, if nodata value is 0 and the band is A, the algebra may be `(A=0)*255`.

Comment: Sorry, I edit my previous comment. Also, the formula `(A=0)` is enough to assign 1 values to nodata and 0 to the rest.

Comment: Thank yo Gabriel for your reply. I am going to try your method, but I will assign value to nodata first.

Comment: IsNull produces a raster containing 0's and 1's, 1 for NoData and 0 for any cell that has a value. You will find that polygonizing the IsNull output will not be as intense regardless of cell size; quite often NoData cells appear together and become one polygon. You could also resample using Aggregate https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000034000000 your IsNull raster to a larger cell size with the statistic type of 'maximum' then convert that to polygons, any output cells that have a value of 1 indicates that one or more of the contributing cells is NoData.

Comment: Can a raster that has nodata cells, not have a value assigned to nodata?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can usually see NoData cells without Spatial Analyst, directly from the raster.

On the Symbology tab, look for the Display NoData As drop down button. This is usually set to no fill/no color. You can change this to a strong color (and perhaps change other symbology for the raster to grays). The no data cells should be easy to spot. Of course, if your no data cells are distributed in tiny clusters around your raster, they may not show well and you would need to use Spatial Analyst to find them.